# How can I find html elements that contain specific text in an html comment?

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint, comments

I'm trying to use jQuery to identify <td> elements which contain specific HTML comment text.  The standard ":contains" selector doesn't seem to be looking into the comments.  My context here is that I want to dynamically add some content to that same td element.  Here's a sample of the target td:

```
<TD valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px">
        <!-- FieldName="Title"
             FieldInternalName="Title"
             FieldType="SPFieldText"
          -->
            <span dir="none">
        <input name="ctl00$m$g_0b1e4ca3_9450_4f3e_b3af_8134fe014ea5$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_0b1e4ca3_9450_4f3e_b3af_8134fe014ea5_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Title" class="ms-long" /><br>
    </span>


        </TD>
```

This html is generated by SharePoint as part of a new list item form, and I really want to find the td in my document whose "FieldInternalName" in the comment matches some text string.  How can I use jQuery  (or any javascript would really be okay) to best find these td elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could grab the `innerHTML` of the element and run a regular expression over it.

Example:

```
// HTML: <div id="myElement">Lorem <!-- a comment --> ipsum.</div>

var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
alert(element.innerHTML); // alerts "Lorem <!-- a comment --> ipsum."
// here you could run a regular expression
```

**Update:** a more comprehensive example (with jQuery):

```
var tds = $('td'), match;
tds.each(function(index, element) {
    match = $(element).innerHTML.match(/FieldInternalName="(^["])"/);
    if (match) alert(match);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML.indexOf(text_string) != -1) { //do something }
```