# Finding next input element after comment tag

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

Very similar to the question asked here: [How can I find html elements that contain specific text in an html comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611662/how-can-i-find-html-elements-that-contain-specific-text-in-an-html-comment)

I'm looking to find the name of next form input field after a comment containing specific text. The form is automatically generated by SharePoint so manipulating/adding id's is out. Here's an example of a form snippet...

```
<tr>
<td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Some Form Field</nobr>
    </h3>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <!--  FieldName="My Field Name" FieldInternalName="MyFieldName" FieldType="SPFieldText"  -->
    <span dir="none">
        <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$idDocSetDisplayFormWebPart$ctl00$ctl02$ctl08$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_idDocSetDisplayFormWebPart_ctl00_ctl02_ctl08_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Field Name" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" /><br />
    </span>
</td>
```

Note: SharePoint gives you the FieldName, FieldInternalName, and FieldType in an HTML comment preceding the actual form input. (It also gives the input a crazy name and ID, but that's a different topic.)

I'm using ajax to pull data from another item in order to pre-populate certain fields in this form. I'm iterating over the form fields and can successfully find the appropriate comment using...

```
function fnFindThisComment(){
var myFieldInternalName = 'FieldInternalName="MyFieldName"'; // hardcoded for example purposes
$("*").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8; }).each(function(i, e){ 
  match = this.innerHTML.match(myFieldInternalName) ;
     if (match){alert(match);}  });
```

The problem is I can't get the name or id of the input field. I've tried numerous variations of "myInputName = $(this).nextAll("input").attr("name")" but it always comes up as undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I've found using the `nobr` tag is easier in most circumstances.

`$('nobr:contains("Some Form Field")').closest('tr').find('input').attr('id');`

This gets the form control without messing around with custom functions and comment tags. Please note that 'Person' selection fields are a bit trickier, grab the [SPServices jQuery plugin](http://spservices.codeplex.com) for working with those (and other things).